# How to get path to file in android apk

Tags: android

My app depends on 3 different files. I already put the two larger ones as expansion files which seems to work fine. Now I don't know where to put the third one (small file). I tried the `raw` folder but actually I don't know what the path of the file is once it is in those folders.

I tried this here for the `raw` folder

```
myClassifier.loadModel( pathToExpansionFiles + "/File1",
                        pathToExpansionFiles + "/File2",
                        R.raw.File3);
```

However the return value of `R.raw.File3` is an integer, but the function `myClassifier` expects a string that is the path to `File3`. Has anyone an idea how to do that?

Comment: Why aren't you using the `assets` folder, instead of `raw` folder?

Comment: I couldn't get it working with the assets folder either so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried the raw folder but actually I don't know what the path of the file is once it is in those folders.

There is no path to it. That is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the device. It is merely an entry inside your APK file.

> but the function myClassifier expects a string that is the path to File3

Either switch to some library that works with an `InputStream` (from `getResources().openRawResource()`) or make a copy of the data to a local file using that `InputStream` yourself.

Comment: The last tip sounds promising for my case as the file is an ascii file. Do you have a code snippet for that? If not I can search it up and post the result here. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: @mcExchange: I tend to use assets over raw resources, as assets is a bit more flexible (e.g., can have subdirectories). [This](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v7.5/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/cp/v4file/FilesCPDemo.java#L37-L46) and [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v7.5/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/cp/v4file/FilesCPDemo.java#L37-L46) show copying an asset to a file. Just replace the source of the `InputStream` to use `getResources().openRawResource()`.

Comment: Both links are the same. However the code snippet is fine. It does copy the file from assets to some local folder. In my case I chose `Environment.getExternalStorage().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/obb/com.myPackage.name/File3`. Unfortunately I cannot reference the file in that folder either. At least android complains about not finding the file. It's weird because I guess the path should be `/storage/sdcard0/...` but on my test phone the file is under `/storage/emulated/legacy/...` . But I guess this is another problem / question. Thx so far

Comment: @mcExchange: "Both links are the same" -- whoops, sorry, the second one was [to highlight lines 57-68](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v7.5/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/cp/v4file/FilesCPDemo.java#L57-L68). "In my case I chose" -- don't write there. Use an officially supported location (`getFilesDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir()`, etc.). "I guess the path should be..." -- probably not. The paths returned by methods will not necessarily map 1:1 to the filesystem, to handle things like multiple user accounts.